# RESTws POST List (text) field type Error

Tags: 8

I'm using RESTws and POSTing a JSON object to "/node". Everything works fine until I include a List text field (checkbox type). The field in question is:

```
...
"field_days_closed_v": ["Monday", "Tuesday"],
...
```

When I post I get this error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to RestWSBaseFormat::getResourceReferenceValue() 
>       must be of the type array, string given, called in .../restws/restws.formats.inc on line 278 and defined in RestWSBaseFormat->getResourceReferenceValue() line 311

My JSON is:

```
{
  "body": {
    "format": "filtered_html",
    "summary": "",
    "value": "test"
  },
  "field_opening_times_t": {
    "format": "filtered_html",
    "value": "Daily"
  },
  "field_price_category": "",
  "field_price_text_t": {
    "format": "filtered_html",
    "value": "<p>Free entry</p>"
  },
  "title": "Mark test test test",
  "type": "primary_article"
}
```

The field is a List(text) and the widget type is Check boxes/radio buttons. Values are:

```
Monday|Monday
Tuesday|Tuesday
Wednesday|Wednesday
Thursday|Thursday
Friday|Friday
Saturday|Saturday
Sunday|Sunday
```

Am I right in thinking it is just an array that should be POSTed?

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see `field_days_closed_v` in your JSON format!. Where is it? and I'm pretty sure that the JSON format in my answer works for the field type you mentioned. So try to send the exact JSON format (by ignoring other fields) and see.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON format for list (text) for checkbox type would looks like follows

```
{"title":"My Day","type":"page","field_days_closed_v":{"und":["sunday", "monday"]}}
```

I've tested this, and working fine.

Here `field_days_closed_v` is the machine name of the  List text field (checkbox type). similarly `sunday`, `monday` are the values of checkbox type so change them accordingly.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. It still isn't working for me however. I've tried these variations:  
`"field_days_closed_v": { "und" : [ "Sunday", "Monday" ] },`
Response: 406 Not Acceptable: Invalid value for resource reference given. And then:
`"field_days_closed_v": { "und" : [ { "value" : "Sunday" }, { "value" : "Monday" } ] },`
Response: 406 Not Acceptable: Invalid value for resource reference given.

Comment: @MarkRobson Sorry for the delay. Can you post your complete JSON format here. It seems issue with other fields

Comment: This is all very confusing. I have fields that have "£" in them, and this breaks the import too :-(

Comment: @MarkRobson Does it works fine without "£"? Have you checked that?

Comment: @MarkRobson Have a look at this post - [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19176024/3249111)

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty familiar with json.org. How are you testing it? Did you add a £ on the code that you tested with?

Comment: @MarkRobson I use POSTER Add-on for Firefox to send json format to rest service. I didn't have time to check your scenario. I'll try to do that today. :)

Comment: @MarkRobson I was busy yesterday. Just checked your scenario. It's working fine, even I add `£` ot JSON format. If that doesn't work for you try something like `"field_text":{"und":[{"value":"\u00a3"}]}` for pound symbol.

Comment: you are right, this is a very strange one. When I POST using Chrome Postaman it works fine. When I send using Node it breaks on just that field if it has any content. :'(

Comment: FOUND THE ANSWER!!!! I'm using Node.js, so POST requires the length of the data sent. I was using string.length, but, when a character such as "£" is used, the .length is not correct. I removed this header from Node and it worked! Arrghh!!

Comment: @MarkRobson Great!!.. :) Glad you solved your problem :)

Comment: However, I'm still stuck with the original problem of posting a "List (text)" Field type that has a "Check boxes/radio buttons" widget :'(

Comment: I tried adding the patch described https://www.drupal.org/node/2070213#comment-9503217 but still no joy. Did your code work?